# Recover pictures from an SD card

Tags: images, data-recovery

I have an SD card from a few years ago, and when I try to open my old pictures in my laptop, it says that the format is not supported (it's jpg though). I tried to recover the files with disk-drill and with recuva. It doesn't seem to help. Is there another recommended software that I can try?

Comment: What is your OS, have you try to copy file to local disk?

Comment: What is the **file system** of the SD card? Usually, FAT32, which is readable on most PC's. "JPG" is just a file type, and can be copied to almost *any* OS. If you do not know the file system, at least mention the camera make and model that took the photos.

Comment: Can you share a file via Google Drive for example? Do file properties look as expected, file size specifically?

Comment: If JPG files fail to open, they could be corrupted, named incorrectly (e.g. TIFF named as JPG) or encoded in a rarely-supported format like Lossless-JPEG (common JPEG files are Lossy). My employer’s imaging products can open images even if they’re named incorrectly or if they have uncommon encoding. Download the free evaluation of [LEADTOOLS ePrint printer driver and file converter](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Products/ePrint-Professional) then try to open your files in the ePrint Workstation app, and if the files are not corrupted, ePrint should open them and convert them to other formats.